# How to display SOAP Request Message on client side application before request is sent or if request is not sent?

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client, soaphandler

I have to build a UI that consumes and needs to display the xml request and responses to a SOAP Web Service. 
(This is the first time I am working with SOAP and also my first stack question).
All the questions I've seen only answer half of what I'm asking.

Is there a way to display the request xml **even if the soap request is not sent?**

This code snippet is me binding the ServicePort object (generated by wsimport), to MyHandler, which implements `SOAPHandler <SOAPMessageContext>`

```
            eftServicePort = new EFTService(new URL(uri)).getEFTPort();
            handler = new MyHandler();
            Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) eftServicePort).getBinding();
            List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
            handlerList.add(handler);
            binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

This works fine when the URI is correct. I can display both the request and response xml on screen.

If the uri is incorrect/invalid (at the first line) an exception is thrown and the handler object is not created or bound to the ServicePort object.